# Google DoubleClick Implementation for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, double-click

I downloaded the Google DoubleClick SDK for iOS and am plugging it into a project. Within the SDK download there is a demonstration project named DoubleClickExample which builds without issue and executes. However the test credentials it utilises do not seem to generate ads. Instead, the delegate method loadFailed is called and I get the following error message:

**Load Failed: Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=5 "Request Error: No matching ad" UserInfo=0x6331de0 {k=sdktest/testing;kw=test, color_bg=FFFFFF, NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No matching ad}**

The Code=5 seems to be a SOAP error code - [source](http://code.google.com/apis/dfa/docs/error_codes.html)

**You are not authorized to perform this operation.**

Has anyone...

a) encountered the same issue?

b) managed to overcome this in a test environment?

c) managed to overcome this with a real active DoubleClick account?

I do not have a DoubleClick account as I am implementing this for a client so I was genuinely hoping that the out of the box test code would function.

I'm currently building under xcode 3.2.6 for the sake of the current code base but I have compiled the DoubleClickExample under xcode 4 as well, with the same result.

Any help / guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Step #1: Get Doubleclick account....... Step #2: Read documentation

Comment: @DAMO Please help me if you have got the solution.i am facing the same problem with google DoubleClick

Comment: I havent got a solution per se. This was some time ago and the only joy I had was to get an account or as it was - get my clients account details. Which is fatuous really as it relies on the client let me look at their account which was a huge problem for me at the time. And I guess for you too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did u know that

> In order to show DoubleClick ads, you
>   must have an active DoubleClick Mobile
>   account

Pls go through this [Google Double Click](http://code.google.com/mobile/afma_ads/docs/ios/doubleclick/#afma-gettingstarted)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I think I am missing the point of the test credentials... but I will go and get a 'real' 'test' account now :-/

Comment: @Damo  same problem i am facing please help me.and what do you mean by test credentials...Please help me ...

Comment: @7KV7 i have active Double Click Mobile account still facing same problem. i am getting this error log 
Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=5 "Request Error: No matching ad" UserInfo=0x7348850 {k=cen_mobile_test/LatestNews;key=cen_mobile_test;sz=320x50, csit=1, NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No matching ad, color_bg=FFFFFF, c=i}
please help me where i am wrong